# On the monoidal product of comodules

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{V}$ a symmetric monoidal category. A commutative comonoid is a triple $(A, \delta, \epsilon)$ whit $\delta: A \to A\otimes A$, $\epsilon: A\to I$ by the dual of monoid axioms. Given two commutative comonoids
$(A_k, \delta_k, \epsilon_k)\ k=1, 2$ its monoidal product $(A_1\otimes A_2)$ ha a natural structure of a comonoid $(A_1\otimes A_2, \delta, \epsilon)$. We have the projection $\pi_1: A_1\otimes A_2\xrightarrow{1\otimes \epsilon_2} A_1\otimes I \cong A_1 $, $\pi_2: A_1\otimes A_2\xrightarrow{\epsilon_1\otimes 1} I\otimes A_2 \cong A_2 $. I ask if  this could be  a product (the limit on two-elements discrete set) on the category of commutative comonoids of $\mathcal{V}$.

EDIT: I  specify that I mean **commutative** comonoids

Answer (score 3):

*This part of the answer refers to the original question.* By duality, you ask if the tensor product of two monoids (with the usual monoid structure, which can be remembered by $(a \otimes b)(a' \otimes b') := aa' \otimes bb'$) is the coproduct of the two monoids. This is well-known to be false. If $A_1 \to M$ and $A_2 \to M$ are monoid homomorphisms, we get a map $A_1 \otimes A_2 \to M$, but this doesn't have to be a homomorphims of monoids unless $M$ is commutative. This also shows that everything works out fine if we work with *commutative* monoids (or dually cocommutative comonoids).

*Proof for the commutative case.* One checks that $A_1 \otimes A_2$ with the multiplication $(A_1 \otimes A_2) \otimes (A_1 \otimes A_2) \xrightarrow{S} (A_1 \otimes A_1) \otimes (A_2 \otimes A_2) \to A_1 \otimes A_2$ (where $S$ stands for the obvious symmetry) is a commutative monoid, I won't spell that out. The inclusions are given by $\iota_1 : A_1 \cong A_1 \otimes 1 \to A_1 \otimes A_2$ (induced by the unit $1 \to A_2$) and $\iota_2 : A_2 \cong 1 \otimes A_2 \to A_1 \otimes A_2$; they are easily seen to be homomorphisms. Let $f_1 : A_1 \to M$ and $f_2 : A_2 \to M$ be homomorphisms of commutative monoids. Define $f : A_1 \otimes A_2 \to M$ as the composition of $f_1 \otimes f_2 : A_1 \otimes A_2 \to M \otimes M$ with the multiplication map $M \otimes M \to M$. Then $f$ is a homomorphism: It is unital because

$$\begin{array}{c}
1 & \rightarrow & 1 \otimes 1  & \rightarrow & 1\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
A_1 \otimes A_2 & \rightarrow & M \otimes M & \rightarrow & M  \end{array}$$

commutes. It is multiplicative because

$$\begin{array}{c}
(A_1 \otimes A_2) \otimes (A_1 \otimes A_2) & \rightarrow & (M \otimes M) \otimes (M \otimes M) & \rightarrow & M \otimes M \\
~~ \downarrow S  & & ~ \downarrow S && \\
(A_1 \otimes A_1) \otimes (A_2 \otimes A_2) & \rightarrow & (M \otimes M) \otimes (M \otimes M)  && \downarrow\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & &  \\
A_1 \otimes A_2 & \rightarrow & M \otimes M & \rightarrow & M 
\end{array}$$

commutes (the right square because $M$ is commutative, the left squares by naturality of the symmetry and because of functoriality of $\otimes$). We have $f \circ \iota_1 = f_1$, since $f_2$ is unital:

$$\begin{array}{c}
A_1 & \rightarrow & A_1 \otimes 1 & \rightarrow & M \otimes 1 & \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow && \downarrow & \searrow \\
A_1 \otimes A_2 & \rightarrow & A_1 \otimes M & \rightarrow & M \otimes M & \rightarrow & M
\end{array}$$

Now let $g : A_1 \otimes A_2 \to M$ be a homomorphism of monoids with $g \circ \iota_1 = f_1$ and $g \circ \iota_2 = f_2$. We claim $g=f$. This follows from the following commutative diagram:

$$\begin{array}{c}
A_1 \otimes A_2 & \rightarrow & (A_1 \otimes 1) \otimes (1 \otimes A_2) & \rightarrow & (A_1 \otimes A_2) \otimes (A_1 \otimes A_2) & \rightarrow & M \otimes M \\
&& ~~~~ \downarrow  S=\mathrm{id} & & ~~ \downarrow  S & & \\
\parallel && (A_1 \otimes 1) \otimes (1 \otimes A_2) & \rightarrow & (A_1 \otimes A_1) \otimes (A_2 \otimes A_2) & & \downarrow \\
& \nearrow & & & \downarrow & & \\
A_1 \otimes A_2 && = & & A_1 \otimes A_2 & \rightarrow & M
\end{array}$$

Namely, this shows that $g$ is the composition of $(g \circ \iota_1) \otimes (g \circ \iota_2)$ with the multiplication of $M$.